# Can an action be called from a separate view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

I am coding an app in Xcode and would like to know if it is possible to have an action called from a button in separate view controller.

For example, if there is a button on ViewController1 and the user presses the button, I would like an image to appear on ViewController2 and stay there even if the user navigates back to ViewController1 and then back to ViewController2 again. Can anyone help me please? Thank you.

UPDATED: I found a the answer to the question at the link below...

[if my "button" is selected on view controller 1, then image should then display and stay on view controller 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25312484/if-my-button-is-selected-on-view-controller-1-then-image-should-then-display/25313358#25313358)

Comment: Since you tagged this with MVC, I'd suggest you shouldn't have VC1 updating anything on VC2's view. If you're going to do anything, you should have VC1 update your model to reflect the state change, set a property in VC2 when you transition to it (e.g. in `prepareForSegue` if using storyboards), and then VC2 will be responsible for showing the appropriate image on the basis of the model. If you want more detail, you should expand your question showing us your model, how you're transitioning from VC1 to VC2, etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25312484/if-my-button-is-selected-on-view-controller-1-then-image-should-then-display/25313358#25313358

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. If you declare the instance of ViewController2 within ViewController 1, then you can have full control over what's going on in ViewController2 at all times from ViewController1. For instance, in the .m, have

```
@implementation ViewController1
@synthesize viewController2

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    viewController2 = [[UIViewControllerClass alloc] init];
}
```

and in the .h, have

```
@interface ViewController1
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewControllerClass *viewController2;
```

This will make sure that ARC does not scrap your second ViewController before you're done with it, which in this case is when you terminate the program.

Then, you can simply call methods that belong to ViewController2 from ViewController1 like you would with any other class.

```
[viewController2 doSomethingWithThisData: stringData];
```

Answer (score 0):

A few considerations not yet mentioned...

Depending on how you transition between viewControllers & where the shared data (images etc) are set,  one option is for VC2 to have a public @property to set the image.

```
VC2.h 

@IBOutlet (nonatomic, weak) UIImageView *imageFromVC1;
```

VC1 should import the VC2 header so it can create & hold an instance of VC2 and set the image.
You'd need to keep track of VC2's state in VC1, as a @property of VC1.

```
    VC1.m 
     #import VC2.h 

     @interface VC1()
        @property (nonatomic, strong) VC2 *viewController2;
     @end 

     @implementation
     ...
```

Note that this does *not* need to go in the .h for VC1 - unless other classes need to know about it, this should be a private property in a class extension of .m & not exposed in the header. You don't need to use `@synthesize` anymore either - that's automatic if you're using XCode 4.4 or later.

The issue at this point is that VC2 shouldn't exist until it's needed (it's a waste of limited memory). You could create it right away in `-viewDidLoad` in VC1, but then it's just sitting there sucking up resources.

Better option is 'lazy instantiation' where you only create a VC2 instance when you transition to showing VC2 for the first time. Also set the @property in VC1 at this point.

```
-(void)someMethodToShowVC2OrStoryboardPrepareForSegue {
    if (self.viewController2 == nil) 
    {
       self.viewController2 = [[VC2 alloc] init];
    }
    //handle transition & set up VC2.
}
```

You could also ask VC2 to be sure it has the public method that allows you can set the image. If it doesn't, it will crash. By writing & importing the VC2 header obviously you should know that the method exists - this is just a defensive practice and alternative to sending the message to VC2 directly:

```
if ([self.viewController2 respondsToSelector:@selector(setImageFromVC1)])
{
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageName"];
[self.viewController2 setImageFromVC1:myImage];
}
```

Here "setImageFromVC1" is the name of the setter method that is automatically generated when you use an @property. Change this if you use another name. 
Alternative is to use dot notation: `self.viewController2.imageFromVC1 = myImage;`

Note that this "Key-Value Observing" approach to setting properties on other objects isn't the only, or necessarily the best, approach to doing this - but it works.